# Count rows only if the count matches

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

How can I achieve something like this?

```
select count(distinct a.name) 
from table_a as a 
where (
    select count(*) 
    from table_b as b 
    where b.id = a.id
  ) = (
    select count(*) 
    from table_c as c 
    where c.id = a.id
);
```

I want to count rows only if the count in the two different tables related to first are having the same count of IDs. Assume that we are using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Why does you code not work?

Answer (score 0):

i've attempted to mock up the situation you described.

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (name VARCHAR, id INT8);
CREATE TABLE b (id INT8);
CREATE TABLE c (id INT8);
INSERT
  INTO a
VALUES ('none', 1),
       ('equal', 2),
       ('more_b', 3),
       ('more_c', 4),
       ('no_b', 5),
       ('no_c', 6);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (2), (3), (3), (4), (6);
INSERT INTO c VALUES (2), (3), (4), (4), (5);
SELECT name
  FROM (
          WITH b_agg AS (
                        SELECT a.id,
                               name,
                               CASE
                               WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 0
                               ELSE count(*)
                               END AS smart_count
                          FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
                      GROUP BY a.id, a.name, b.id
                     ),
               c_agg AS (
                        SELECT a.id,
                               name,
                               CASE
                               WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN 0
                               ELSE count(*)
                               END AS smart_count
                          FROM a LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
                      GROUP BY a.id, a.name, c.id
                     )
        SELECT a.name,
               a.id,
               b_agg.smart_count AS b_count,
               c_agg.smart_count AS c_count
          FROM a JOIN b_agg ON a.id = b_agg.id JOIN c_agg ON a.id = c_agg.id
       ) AS t
 WHERE b_count = c_count;
DROP TABLE a;
DROP TABLE b;
DROP TABLE c;
```

when run, this produces

```
 name
-------
 equal
 none
(2 rows)
```